# How to get content model for complex datatype

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xmlbeans

I need the contentModel for complex type declared in xsd my XSD is as follows:

```
<element name="add">
<complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element name="no1" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
  <element name="no2" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5"/>
 </sequence>
</complexType>
```

i am using the following code for that :

```
//elem is ScheamType for the rootnode , in this case it is add
    if (elem != null) {

        System.out.println("\ncontent of "+elem +"   is    "+elem.getContentType());
         if(elem.getContentType()==3||elem.getContentType()==4)

        {   
             SchemaParticle particle=elem.getContentModel();

        for( SchemaParticle p:particle.getParticleChildren())

        {

             System.out.println("\nchild:"+p.getName()+"\ttype:"+p.getType().getName().getLocalPart());

        }

        }
```

but it given NullPointerException for the SchemaParticle object which is returned by getContentModel()

the code works fine for the following xsd:

`<complexType name="Employee">
    <sequence>
     <element name="empid" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="empname" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>`

Comment: To answer your question requires reading through 100 lines of code. Cut your code sample down by only posting the relevant bits. Also, why not provide the XML output which causes the XSD validation error? That might help don't you think?

Comment: @hugh Now you can have a look and i am reading wsdl file which contains the XSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :

```
//The elem is the SchemaType variable
SchemaParticle rootSchemaParticle = elem.getContentModel();
        SchemaLocalElement rootSchemaLocalElement = (SchemaLocalElement) rootSchemaParticle;
        //Get the SchemaType for the element.
        SchemaType rootSchemaType = rootSchemaLocalElement.getType();
        //Get the content Model of the root Element ie; the Children Structure for elem
        SchemaParticle childrenSchemaparticle = rootSchemaType.getContentModel();

        if (childrenSchemaparticle != null) {// Operation has non zero child element
            if (childrenSchemaparticle.countOfParticleChild() > 0) {// multiple child elements
                for (int i = 0; i < childrenSchemaparticle
                        .countOfParticleChild(); i++) {
                    paraName = childrenSchemaparticle.getParticleChild(i).getName().getLocalPart();
                    SchemaLocalElement childSchemaLocalElement = (SchemaLocalElement) childrenSchemaparticle.getParticleChild(i);
                    minOccur = childSchemaLocalElement.getMinOccurs().longValue();
                    maxOccur = childSchemaLocalElement.getMaxOccurs().longValue();
                    SchemaType childSchemaType = childSchemaLocalElement.getType();
                    dataType = childSchemaType.getName().getLocalPart();
                    System.out.println("parameter Name "+paraName + " Datatype "+dataType+" Minoccur "+minOccur+" MaxOccur "+maxOccur);                 
                }
            } else {// Single child                 
                paraName = childrenSchemaparticle.getName().getLocalPart();
                minOccur = childrenSchemaparticle.getMinOccurs().longValue();
                maxOccur = childrenSchemaparticle.getMaxOccurs().longValue();
                SchemaLocalElement childSchemaLocalElement = (SchemaLocalElement) childrenSchemaparticle;
                SchemaType childSchemaType = childSchemaLocalElement.getType();
                dataType = childSchemaType.getName().getLocalPart();
                System.out.println("parameter Name "+paraName + " Datatype "+dataType+" Minoccur "+minOccur+" MaxOccur "+maxOccur);
            }
        }
```

The Difference in handling the single child and multiple children is because of the difference in the type of the  Particle , as it is ELEMENT for single child and SEQUENCE for the multiple childrens. Ref for details:http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaParticle.html